# How to make sku unique?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, sku

I just found out I have duplicated sku. Not sure how this could happen since [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) with `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import::BEHAVIOR_REPLACE` should always replace those products. Looks like I did messup one import last year. All product have the same date for `getCreatedAt()`.

Anyway, if I look at sku attribute config I can not change `Unique Value` to `Yes`. Is this not possible in general or only because I have duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unique Value" against SKU should be "yes" by default (and not let you change it).  I would suggest that because you have duplicate SKUs, you're having an issue, or that a plugin / update has changed the default behaviour of this attribute.